# i tried adding a figure to my empty array using push

Tags: javascript, push

I tried using the push to add a number to my empty array and its not working, at all.
below is my code

```
 var giv = []
    var mes = (2, 3);
    function outPut () {
    output.push(2,3); 
        
    }
    alert(output);
```

Comment: You have to push to the correct variable name. Either rename `giv` to `output`, or use `giv.push()` instead. And fix the rest of the syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is all messed up in terms of variables and function, here is what I think you might be trying to achieve. Is that correct?

```js
var giv = [];

function output (input) {
    giv.push(input);
}

var mes = 2;
output(mes);

mes = 3;
output(mes);

alert(giv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse variables giv and output, here is how you can get rid of the error:

```
var giv = []
var mes = (2, 3);
function outPut () {
    giv.push(2,3); 
}
outPut();
alert(giv);
```

Output:

```
[ 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: Don't forget to actually call the function before alerting.